# How to execute a condition based on a returned value using expect

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I'm working on an expect script that will execute a condition based on the returned value from the hardware. I want to use expect to automate this process, however, I'm unsure if I'm going about doing this correctly as shown in the code below.

```
#! /bin/expect 
set timeout 5 
puts "Spawning serial connection"
spawn -open [open /dev/ttys1 w+]
send --"\r"
expect "barebox: /"
send --"?\r"
expect "barebox: /"
#I2C communication to initiate test pattern test
send "i2c_write -b 1 -a 0x50 -r 0x105 -w 0x02 0xf0\r"
expect "barebox: /"
send "i2c_write -b 1 -a 0x50 -r 0x105 -w 0x01 0xf0\r"
expect "barebox: /"
send "i2c_read -b 1 -a 0x50 -r 0x108 -w 0x03 0xh0\r"

#checking to see if value returned matches any of the following conditions
expect{
while{"0x04 0x00}{
  put "FPGA still busy/r"
  send "i2c_read -b 1 -a 0x50 -r 0x108 -w 0x03 0xh0\r"
}
if{"0x00 0x00}{
  put "Test Pattern test successful\r"
}
elseif{"0x08 0x00}{
  put "Test Pattern test failed\r"
}
}
put "End of Test Pattern test\r"
```

Comment: Tcl, like the unix shell, is sensitive to whitespace. Commands must be separated from arguments by whitespace. `if {expression} {body}`, `while {expression} {body}` etc.

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language. take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more comfortable with bash shell.

Comment: `while` and `if` are not keywords (Tcl does not have any keywords in the usual sense), but functions. As with all Tcl functions, you need a space after the function name, in order to separate it from the function arguments.

Comment: Not functions (which are features of `expr`) but *commands*.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your loop and test as:

```
expect {
    "0x04 0x00" {
        puts "FPGA still busy"
        send "i2c_read -b 1 -a 0x50 -r 0x108 -w 0x03 0xh0\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "0x00 0x00" {
        puts "Test Pattern test successful"
    }
    "0x08 0x00" {
        puts "Test Pattern test failed"
    }
}
```

It may be wise to have a delay in your loop so as not to hammer the remote system with continuous requests.  E.g. you could wait 1 second each time by adding the line `sleep 1` before the `send`.  For full details see the docs at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Comment: Whether to sleep depends on how often the pattern is matched; as you wrote it, the code goes back to `expect` so it's not automatically a problem.